# Adjust signature line at end of letter when characters extend below horizontal line

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, multicol

I am using LaTeX to write a contract and am trying to get the formatting of my signature block to look right.  I have gotten it to display pretty well, but there is one minor annoyance with the signature line.  I'm using a scanned image of my signature and superimposing it over a horizontal line, as shown.  However, I can't get the line spacing to match up with the unfilled line for the Client in the righthand column.

In the current version below, you can see that the horizontal line for my signature is set above My Name with quite a bit of extra space.

[image: Incorrect version]

What it should look like is as shown below, where both columns have the same vertical spacing.

[image: Proper version]

My MWE is shown below.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=1.25in,left=1in,right=1in,bottom=1.25in,showframe=false,headheight=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[scaled]{uarial}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{color,soul}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\normalsize\bfseries}

\def\mydate{\leavevmode\hbox{\the\year/\twodigits\month/\twodigits\day}}
\def\twodigits#1{\ifnum#1<10 0\fi\the#1}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\newcommand{\MyMargin}{0.5in}   %Define global margin

\begin{document}
    
Sincerely,

\vspace{12pt}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \noindent
    \begin{tabular}{@{}p{2.5in}}
        My Business Name\\
        \\
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[thin](0,0)--(2.5in,0)node[midway,yshift=0.25cm](c){\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{signature.png}};
            \node[yshift=1cm] at (c.south) {};
        \end{tikzpicture}\\
        My Name\\
        Owner\\
        Address\\
        City, State ZIP\\
        \\
        \quad\quad \mydate\\
        \hline
        \vspace{-0.2cm}Date\\
    \end{tabular}
    

    
    \noindent
    \begin{tabular}{p{2.5in}}
        Agreed to and Accepted by:\\
        \\
        \\
        \hrulefill\\
        Client Name \\
        Client's Business Name     %do not include \\, it's defined with \ClientBus
        \\
        \\
        \hrulefill\\
        Date\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of directly writing `\includegraphics`, you could write, say, `\raisebox{-10pt}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{signature.png}}`, where you should modify the `-10pt` to an appropriate value to make it fit.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `multicols`, just to make top-aligned `tabular`s with the same spacing for the first lines.

For fixed width columns it's better to use the `w` column type provided by `array`.

The signature can be added in the empty row as a box that takes no vertical space and can be raised or lowered at will. Note: I used `height` just to emulate your picture with a generic image.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[
  letterpaper,
  top=1.25in,
  left=1in,
  right=1in,
  bottom=1.25in,
  showframe=false,
  headheight=1in
]{geometry}
\usepackage[scaled]{uarial}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\allsectionsfont{\normalsize\bfseries}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\mydate{\mbox{\the\year/\two@digits\month/\two@digits\day}}
\makeatother

%\newcommand{\MyMargin}{0.5in}   %Define global margin

\begin{document}
    
Sincerely,

\vspace{12pt}

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}w{l}{2.5in}@{}}
  My Business Name \\[2ex]
  \multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{%
    \raisebox{-10pt}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=1.5in,height=0.7cm]{example-image}}%
  } \\
  \hline
  \\[-1ex]
  My Name\\
  Owner\\
  Address\\
  City, State ZIP\\
  \\
  \quad\quad \mydate\\
  \hline
  Date\\
\end{tabular}\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}w{l}{2.5in}@{}}
  Agreed to and Accepted by:\\[2ex]
  \\
  \hline
  \\[-1ex]
  Client Name \\
  Client's Business Name \\
  \\ \\
  \hline
  Date\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I usually make all my documents of this type using tikz in the standalone environment, defining the size of the sheet to the largest square of the drawing; Mainly because I can generate them in batches, for multiple recipients with the same message or messages according to specific topics as the definitions are ordered. taking advantage of the fact that each standalone tikzpicture environment represents one page and of course several can be iterated.

For your particular example I added the option in the tikzpicture environment, you can use the constant `\linewidth` to define the width then create some variables that allow you to control the separation and width of the middle space and some additions and subtractions to place them in the corresponding position. Define some nodes with names to be able to place the signatures later and use the calc library for the respective displacements; I also added some signatures that can be obtained using `inkscape` and the `plugin` that generates the code for `tikz` in case you want everything to be vector.

**Result with the line of code `\def\helplines{none}`**

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=1.25in,left=1in,right=1in,bottom=1.25in,showframe=false,headheight=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[scaled]{uarial}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,backgrounds}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\normalsize\bfseries}

\def\mydate{\leavevmode\hbox{\the\year/\twodigits\month/\twodigits\day}}
\def\twodigits#1{\ifnum#1<10 0\fi\the#1}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\newcommand{\MyMargin}{0.5in}   %Define global margin

\def\MySignature#1#2#3{%\MySignature{position}{scale}{line widht}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)},scale=#2]
        %\fill(0,0) circle (5pt); uncoment to find the origin or insertion point
        \path[draw,x=1pt,y=1pt,shift={(-170, 735.3)}, line width=#3]%points obtained in pt using svg to tkz inkscape externsion https://github.com/xyz2tex/svg2tikz
        (96.7, -725.4).. controls (96.7, -725.4) and (93.7, -729.8) .. (91.8, -728.8).. controls (89.8, -727.9) and (90.6, -723.0) .. (95.5, -715.6).. controls (100.5, -708.3) and (104.0, -706.1) .. (105.5, -706.8).. controls (107.1, -707.5) and (103.4, -717.8) .. (100.2, -722.1).. controls (97.0, -726.3) and (96.6, -727.0) .. (97.2, -727.5).. controls (97.8, -728.0) and (105.0, -723.2) .. (104.2, -722.1).. controls (103.4, -720.9) and (100.8, -725.6) .. (101.9, -725.9).. controls (103.0, -726.3) and (108.3, -721.1) .. (108.3, -721.1).. controls (108.3, -721.1) and (105.2, -724.3) .. (106.1, -724.9).. controls (107.0, -725.4) and (115.8, -719.9) .. (115.8, -719.9).. controls (115.8, -719.9) and (109.4, -724.8) .. (110.9, -725.3).. controls (112.3, -725.7) and (114.4, -723.5) .. (116.3, -719.9).. controls (118.2, -716.4) and (122.9, -705.3) .. (124.4, -706.1).. controls (125.9, -706.9) and (113.5, -722.7) .. (114.8, -723.7).. controls (116.0, -724.7) and (122.6, -717.6) .. (122.6, -717.6).. controls (122.6, -717.6) and (120.0, -719.9) .. (120.5, -720.5).. controls (121.1, -721.2) and (125.3, -718.4) .. (125.3, -718.4).. controls (125.3, -718.4) and (122.1, -722.5) .. (122.7, -722.9).. controls (123.4, -723.4) and (128.7, -718.3) .. (128.7, -718.3).. controls (128.7, -718.3) and (124.4, -722.7) .. (125.4, -723.3).. controls (126.4, -724.0) and (133.0, -719.1) .. (133.1, -718.3).. controls (133.2, -717.5) and (128.4, -722.3) .. (129.5, -722.6).. controls (130.6, -722.9) and (133.1, -720.8) .. (133.1, -720.8) -- (133.1, -720.7)
        (134.6, -718.1).. controls (134.6, -718.1) and (137.7, -717.0) .. (137.3, -716.1).. controls (136.9, -715.2) and (128.8, -732.2) .. (128.8, -732.2).. controls (128.8, -732.2) and (133.8, -722.9) .. (138.5, -717.1).. controls (143.1, -711.3) and (145.8, -706.5) .. (146.7, -706.9).. controls (147.6, -707.3) and (145.9, -709.1) .. (147.6, -709.8).. controls (149.4, -710.5) and (153.5, -708.5) .. (153.5, -708.5)
        (154.5, -706.1).. controls (149.1, -705.5) and (136.1, -719.3) .. (138.1, -720.5).. controls (140.2, -721.7) and (149.5, -711.8) .. (149.5, -711.8).. controls (149.5, -711.8) and (150.0, -712.2) .. (150.6, -712.2).. controls (151.3, -712.2) and (152.4, -711.3) .. (152.4, -711.3).. controls (152.4, -711.3) and (144.9, -719.3) .. (146.2, -720.1).. controls (147.4, -720.8) and (159.4, -713.9) .. (162.4, -710.4).. controls (165.5, -706.9) and (167.9, -705.0) .. (167.0, -704.3).. controls (166.1, -703.5) and (148.8, -718.4) .. (153.1, -720.3).. controls (157.3, -722.1) and (175.4, -706.8) .. (174.2, -704.7).. controls (172.9, -702.6) and (161.8, -716.1) .. (163.4, -717.6).. controls (165.0, -719.1) and (168.5, -716.1) .. (169.3, -716.4).. controls (170.1, -716.8) and (168.2, -720.2) .. (168.2, -720.2).. controls (168.2, -720.2) and (176.7, -714.4) .. (177.1, -715.4).. controls (177.5, -716.4) and (172.2, -719.1) .. (173.2, -719.7).. controls (174.2, -720.3) and (192.9, -708.3) .. (191.4, -706.4).. controls (189.8, -704.5) and (176.6, -717.8) .. (177.9, -718.8).. controls (179.2, -719.7) and (192.6, -713.6) .. (194.6, -711.0).. controls (196.5, -708.4) and (200.1, -704.7) .. (199.0, -704.1).. controls (197.9, -703.4) and (183.3, -718.2) .. (184.5, -718.8).. controls (185.7, -719.3) and (187.4, -715.3) .. (191.5, -715.5).. controls (195.6, -715.7) and (204.9, -716.6) .. (206.1, -715.4).. controls (207.3, -714.2) and (208.2, -713.2) .. (208.2, -713.2).. controls (208.2, -713.2) and (203.6, -717.1) .. (205.4, -717.8).. controls (207.2, -718.4) and (224.4, -703.5) .. (224.4, -703.5).. controls (224.4, -703.5) and (209.5, -716.2) .. (212.5, -717.5).. controls (215.4, -718.9) and (232.5, -702.1) .. (232.1, -700.6).. controls (231.7, -699.2) and (216.3, -714.3) .. (219.8, -716.1).. controls (223.3, -717.9) and (232.5, -711.1) .. (232.5, -711.1).. controls (232.5, -711.1) and (225.6, -715.4) .. (228.0, -715.4).. controls (230.4, -715.5) and (241.7, -712.6) .. (241.7, -712.6).. controls (241.7, -712.6) and (228.1, -715.8) .. (232.4, -716.7).. controls (236.7, -717.6) and (239.9, -717.5) .. (239.9, -718.6).. controls (239.9, -719.7) and (227.3, -723.6) .. (198.4, -725.3).. controls (169.5, -727.1) and (163.0, -730.3) .. (163.3, -731.3).. controls (163.6, -732.3) and (168.6, -733.9) .. (183.9, -733.4).. controls (199.1, -732.9) and (202.9, -733.2) .. (202.9, -733.2);
    \end{scope}
}

\def\MySignatureB#1#2#3#4{%\MySignature{position}{scale}{line width}{color}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)},scale=#2]
        %\fill(0,0) circle (5pt); uncoment to find the origin or insertion point
        \path[draw,x=1pt,y=1pt,shift={(-190, 720)}, line width=#3,#4]%points obtained in pt using svg to tkz inkscape externsion https://github.com/xyz2tex/svg2tikz
        (152.4, -711.3).. controls (152.4, -711.3) and (144.9, -719.3) .. (146.2, -720.1).. controls (147.4, -720.8) and (159.4, -713.9) .. (162.4, -710.4).. controls (165.5, -706.9) and (167.9, -705.0) .. (167.0, -704.3).. controls (166.1, -703.5) and (148.8, -718.4) .. (153.1, -720.3).. controls (157.3, -722.1) and (175.4, -706.8) .. (174.2, -704.7).. controls (172.9, -702.6) and (161.8, -716.1) .. (163.4, -717.6).. controls (165.0, -719.1) and (168.5, -716.1) .. (169.3, -716.4).. controls (170.1, -716.8) and (168.2, -720.2) .. (168.2, -720.2).. controls (168.2, -720.2) and (176.7, -714.4) .. (177.1, -715.4).. controls (177.5, -716.4) and (172.2, -719.1) .. (173.2, -719.7).. controls (174.2, -720.3) and (192.9, -708.3) .. (191.4, -706.4).. controls (189.8, -704.5) and (176.6, -717.8) .. (177.9, -718.8).. controls (179.2, -719.7) and (192.6, -713.6) .. (194.6, -711.0).. controls (196.5, -708.4) and (200.1, -704.7) .. (199.0, -704.1).. controls (197.9, -703.4) and (183.3, -718.2) .. (184.5, -718.8).. controls (185.7, -719.3) and (187.4, -715.3) .. (191.5, -715.5).. controls (195.6, -715.7) and (204.9, -716.6) .. (206.1, -715.4).. controls (207.3, -714.2) and (208.2, -713.2) .. (208.2, -713.2).. controls (208.2, -713.2) and (203.6, -717.1) .. (205.4, -717.8).. controls (207.2, -718.4) and (224.4, -703.5) .. (224.4, -703.5).. controls (224.4, -703.5) and (209.5, -716.2) .. (212.5, -717.5).. controls (215.4, -718.9) and (232.5, -702.1) .. (232.1, -700.6).. controls (231.7, -699.2) and (216.3, -714.3) .. (219.8, -716.1).. controls (223.3, -717.9) and (232.5, -711.1) .. (232.5, -711.1);
    \end{scope}
}
\def\Acot[#1]#2#3(#4)#5{
    \draw[|<->|,#5] (#1)++(0,-0.3) -- ++(#2,0) node[midway](#4-W){};
    \draw[|<->|,#5] (#1)++(0.3,0) -- ++(0,-#3) node[pos=0.3](#4-H){};
}


\begin{document}
    
    Sincerely,
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\helplines{none} % Default "none" , to see what happens change to your favoryte color.
        \def\midspace{5em}
        \def\topsignatureSpace{5em}
        \def\bottomsignatureSpace{1em}
        \draw(0,0) node[anchor=north west,draw=\helplines](MBN){My Business Name};
        \draw(\linewidth/2+\midspace/2,0) node[anchor=north west,draw=\helplines](CLI){Agreed to and Accepted by:};
        \draw[thick]
        ($(MBN.south west)+(0,-\topsignatureSpace)$) coordinate (a)
            -- ++(\linewidth/2-\midspace/2,0)
            node[pos=0.5,anchor=south](sig1){};
        \draw[thick]
        ($(MBN.south west-|CLI.180)+(0,-\topsignatureSpace)$)coordinate(b)
            -- ++(\linewidth/2-\midspace/2,0)
            node[pos=0.5,anchor=south](sig2){};
        
        \draw($(a)+(0,-\bottomsignatureSpace)$) node[anchor=north west,draw=\helplines, align=left](MBN-dat){
            My Name\\
            Owner\\
            Address\\
            City, State ZIP%
        };
        \draw($(b)+(0,-\bottomsignatureSpace)$) node[anchor=north west,draw=\helplines, align=left](CLI-dat){
            Client Name \\
            Client's Business Name %
        };
        \draw[thick]
        ($(MBN-dat.south west)+(0,-\bottomsignatureSpace-1em)$)coordinate (c) 
            -- ++(\linewidth/2-\midspace/2,0)
            node[pos=0,anchor=north west]{Date}
            node[pos=0.5,anchor=south]{\mydate};
        \draw[thick]
        ($(CLI-dat.south west)+(0,-\bottomsignatureSpace-1em)$)coordinate (d) 
            -- ++(\linewidth/2-\midspace/2,0)
            node[pos=0,anchor=north west]{Date}
            node[pos=0.5,anchor=south]{\mydate};
        \path[draw=\helplines](0,0) rectangle ($(c.south east)+(\linewidth,-2em)$);
        %Put some defined signatures
        \MySignature{$(sig1)+(0,0)$}{1}{1pt}
        \MySignatureB{$(sig2)+(0,0.5pt)$}{1}{1pt}{draw=blue!50!black}
        
        %Code to see the nodes and others (uncoment or erase because for nodes y use the trick to draw te text in white to work with the none option.
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
            \foreach \k in {MBN,MBN-dat,sig1,sig2,CLI,CLI-dat}{
                \draw[draw=\helplines,fill=\helplines] (\k.north west) circle (1.5pt);
                \draw[draw=\helplines](\k.north west)++(6em,-1.5em) node[anchor=180,draw=\helplines,fill=\helplines,inner sep=1pt,text=white]{\tiny \k.north west} -- ++(-1em,0)--  (\k.north west);}
            \foreach \k in {a,b,c,d}{
                \draw[draw=\helplines,fill=\helplines] (\k.north west) circle (1.5pt);
                \draw[draw=\helplines](\k.north west)++(6em,-1.5em) node[anchor=180,draw=\helplines,fill=\helplines,inner sep=1pt,text=white]{\tiny \k.coordinate} -- ++(-1em,0)-- (\k.north west);} %
            \Acot[MBN.south west]{\linewidth}{\topsignatureSpace}(C1){draw=\helplines}
            \draw[draw=\helplines] (C1-W) node[draw=\helplines,fill=\helplines,inner sep=1pt,text=white]{\tiny\verb+\linewidth =+ \texttt{\pgfmathprint{int(\linewidth*3.527)/10}mm} };
            \draw[draw=\helplines] (C1-H) node[anchor=180,draw=\helplines,fill=\helplines,inner sep=1pt,text=white]{\tiny\verb+\topsignature space = 5em =+ \texttt{\pgfmathprint{int(\topsignatureSpace*3.527)/10}mm}};%Actually I dont find how to invoke verb inside a definition. It was done directly
        \end{scope}
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    Text before tikzpicture
    
\end{document}
```

---

**Result with the line of code `\def\helplines{red}`**

[image]

**Erratum:**

In the nodes `sig1` and `sig2` the name of the located points should be `nodename.center`

Comment: Very helpful, and another good way to skin the cat.  Thanks!